# Why elements of BTreeMap<K, V> can be got by smth of different type than K, but it's not the case with Vec and binary_search?

Tags: rust

I have a question to ask. Let's take a look at the following code:

```
use std::collection::BTreeMap;

fn main() {
  let mut hm: BTreeMap<String, String> = BTreeMap::new();
  hm.insert("asdf".to_owned(), "zxcv".to_owned());
  println!("{:?}", hm.get("asdf"));
}
```

So, despite the fact that `BTreeMap` keeps `String`s it accepts other types which can be compared to the key type.

But it's not just the case with `Vec<T>`. Hence the following code would be a blunder:

```
fn main() {
  let v: Vec<String> = vec!["hello".to_owned()];
  println!("{:?}", v.binary_search("hello"));
}
```

This snippet would just fail to be compiled, since `binary_search` calls for a reference to the exactly same type of the provided value. I'm somewhat bewildered why.

Comment: (Btw you can use `binary_search_by` as a workaround: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=bade86970773df1c8703b0f1d9b91991.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There was [an attempt](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/41590) to change the signature of `binary_search` to support accepting a borrowed version of the value but [it broke stuff](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/41590#issuecomment-304115519) and [was declined](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/41590#issuecomment-306861359).

Actually a little surprised this wasn't considered for a new edition.  I guess the fact that `binary_search_by` provides a workaround (as commented by @Dogbert above) has left remedying this a low priority.

Comment: APIs cannot be changed across editions because editions must be able to cooperate across crates. Sadly, there is nothing we can do to prevent inference breakage (though the libs team really wants something).